# Change TextView Dynamically in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, textview, android-adapter

I am creating Grid View with 6 items (2*3).

I am implementing this to change the settings dynamically.

**For that i am using Grid View with Text View's.**

`my code is:`

```
public class MyGridAdaptor extends BaseAdapter
{

    String[] keyPad = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
    String[] functionName = {  "Wi-Fi", "Bluetooth", "GPS", "Brightness",   "Wi-Fi Tethering", "Mobile data", };
    String[][] functionStatus = { { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" } };

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context mContext;
    TextView keyNumber, fName, fStatus;
    RelativeLayout gridItem;
    int counter = 0;

    public MyGridAdaptor(Context applicationContext)
    {
        this.mContext = applicationContext;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        final int pos = position;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int heightAdj = 85;
            view.setMinimumHeight((height - heightAdj) / 2);

            keyNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNo);
            fName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            fStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
            gridItem = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.gridItem);

        }
        else
        {
            view.getTag();
        }
        keyNumber.setText(keyPad[position]);
        fName.setText(functionName[position]);
        fStatus.setText(functionStatus[position][0]);

        gridItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                counter++;

                Toast.makeText(mContext, functionName[pos]+" "+pos+" "+(counter%2)+" "+functionStatus[pos][counter%2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fStatus.setText(functionStatus[pos][counter%2]);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return keyPad.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return keyPad[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

I am getting correct value at **Toast** but values in **Textview** are not changing.

Comment: Why are you not setting the tag for your view?? where is `view.setTag()` . From what I can see you are not actually setting the reference to rStatus if `view == null` is false?

Comment: @Raju-san , check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing it this way? Set onitemselected listener to gridview and on item click you will have index of particular grid item clicked. Using index call getChildAtIndex(grid selected index). This will return you the relative layout and call that relativelayout.getChildAtIndex(3). This is your textview. Update the text and enjoy

Comment: It's working properly. I am waiting for solution exactly like this. I don't know how to get the **childView ** from **setOnItemClickListener()**. That's why i am trying to change using  **Adapter**.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
     gridItem.setTag(position); // Added by Sagar Zala
     gridItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int pos=(Integer)v.getTag(); // Added by Sagar Zala
                counter++;

                Toast.makeText(mContext, functionName[pos]+" "+pos+" "+(counter%2)+" "+functionStatus[pos][counter%2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fStatus.setText(functionStatus[pos][counter%2]);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You forgot the view.setTag(view) statement before return view;

Comment: @Raju-san, add view.setTag(view) before return view; statement

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public class MyGridAdaptor extends BaseAdapter
{

    String[] keyPad = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
    String[] functionName = {  "Wi-Fi", "Bluetooth", "GPS", "Brightness",   "Wi-Fi Tethering", "Mobile data", };
    String[][] functionStatus = { { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" }, { "OFF", "ON" } };

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context mContext;
    TextView keyNumber, fName, fStatus;
    RelativeLayout gridItem;
    int counter = 0;

    public MyGridAdaptor(Context applicationContext)
    {
        this.mContext = applicationContext;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        final int pos = position;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            metrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int heightAdj = 85;
            view.setMinimumHeight((height - heightAdj) / 2);

            viewHolder.keyNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNo);
            viewHolder.fName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            viewHolder.fStatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
            viewHolder.gridItem = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.gridItem);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);

        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.keyNumber.setText(keyPad[position]);
        viewHolder.fName.setText(functionName[position]);
        viewHolder.fStatus.setText(functionStatus[position][0]);

        gridItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                counter++;

                Toast.makeText(mContext, functionName[pos]+" "+pos+" "+(counter%2)+" "+functionStatus[pos][counter%2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewHolder.fStatus.setText(functionStatus[pos][counter%2]);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return keyPad.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return keyPad[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView keyNumber;
        TextView fName;
        TextView fStatus;
        RelativeLayout gridItem;    
    }
}
```

Comment: post the logcat what exactly is null here?

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following code:**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

/*
                ImageView checkImage= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                //checkImage.setTag(R.drawable.checkimg);

                //checkImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkimg);
                    checkImage.setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable(Color.BLUE));
                PaintDrawable drawable = (PaintDrawable) checkImage.getBackground();

                int color = drawable.getPaint().getColor();
                int drawableId = (Integer) checkImage.getTag();
                Log.d("getTag",String.valueOf(color));
  */

                TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);

                text.setText("Selected");
                //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkimg);
            }
        });`
```